# Running while loop to display all rows, but it only displays one row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a while loop to display data regarding flagged posts. I am currently logged in as Conor, who has flagged 2 posts (2 rows in the `flagged_posts` field). But when I execute the below code, only one div is echo's, whereas two should be echo's as he has flagged two posts.

Here is my approach:

```
<?php
// getting id of logged in user, need this to see all the flagged posts from logged in user.
$get_uid = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ");
        $get_d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_uid);
            $user_ident = $get_d ['id'];

// using the above id and getting all the flagged posts which have been flagged by the id obtained
$flagged_by2 = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_posts WHERE flagged_by_id = '$user_ident'");
        $num_of_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($flagged_by2);
        while ($getting_d = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($flagged_by2)){
            $flagged_thought_id = $getting_d['thought_id'];
        }

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE id='$flagged_thought_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $message_content = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['post_details'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $attachent       = $row['attachment'];
    $shared          = $row['shared'];

    echo 
        "   <div class='message_wrapper'>
                <p> Details would be displayed here </p>
            </div>";
} //while closed
```

**Edit**:

Pagination (with Marcin Nabiałek approach):

```
        $flagged_by2 = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_posts WHERE flagged_by_id = '$user_ident'");
        $flagged_ids = [];  
        $num_of_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($flagged_by2);
        while ($getting_d = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($flagged_by2)){
            $flagged_ids[] = $getting_d['thought_id'];
        }
        if (!$flagged_ids) {
            $flagged_ids[] = 0;
        }


            // Pagination - Load more content when bottom of page hit.  
            $limit = 10;

            $page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
            # sql query
            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE id IN " . implode(', ', $flagged_ids)." ORDER BY id DESC");
            # find out query start point
            $start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
            # query for page navigation
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > ($page * $limit) ){
              $next = ++$page;
            }
            //$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE id='$flagged_thought_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE id IN " . implode(', ', $flagged_ids)." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1) {
              header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
              echo "<div class='nothing_to_say'>
                        $ufirstname has no flagged posts.
                    </div>";
              exit();
            }
```

With the above, I get two of the same errors:

mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result - On line:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > ($page * $limit) ){
```

AND

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1) {
```

If I comment these two lines out, then I get another error:
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, on line:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

Comment: I think your queries would be easier as one, personally: `"SELECT * from users where username = '$user' left join flagged_posts on flagged_by_id = users.id left join user_thoughts on user_thoughts.id = flagged_posts.thought_id"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is:

```
$flagged_by2 = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_posts WHERE flagged_by_id = '$user_ident'");
        $num_of_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($flagged_by2);
        while ($getting_d = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($flagged_by2)){
            $flagged_thought_id = $getting_d['thought_id'];
        }

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE id='$flagged_thought_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
```

You set in loop values for same variable and you should have array here. So you should rewrite this code into:

```
$flagged_by2 = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_posts WHERE flagged_by_id = '$user_ident'");
        $flagged_ids = [];  
        $num_of_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($flagged_by2);
        while ($getting_d = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($flagged_by2)){
            $flagged_ids[] = $getting_d['thought_id'];
        }
        if (!$flagged_ids) {
            $flagged_ids[] = 0;
        }

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE id IN " . implode(', ', $flagged_ids)." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
```

However you could make only 1 query as showed an comment and in addition you should use PDO with prepared statements - now yor code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I think you have a missing single quote on this line `$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE id IN " . implode(', ", $flagged_ids)." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");`, As I have never really used `implode` I don't know where the quote should end.

Comment: @Freddy True, fixed this

Comment: I get an error on the line of the query - `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`?

Comment: @Freddy Sorry again, haven't added `[]` in one place. Now should be fine.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't seem to work, but I don't think it is your code. I am using pagination which by default should display the first 10 rows and then present a link progressing to page 2. I have updated my code if you could please take a look.